# PyQt: QValidator Function Definition

Tags: python, pyqt

I am currently using a quite brutal approach in getting of what QValidator would deliver with ease. Locating a simple info on this widget is quite difficult. A code below copied/pasted (after some minor editing) from another post. It creates a dialog with single lineEdit connected to ValidStringLength QValidator which enforces a string size to be 0 < length < 5. I would like to understand where should be a string-cleaning "executable" function placed: inside a fixup() method? Please explain the logic behind QValidator().

---

```
   from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    class ValidStringLength(QtGui.QValidator):
        def __init__(self, min, max, parent):
            QtGui.QValidator.__init__(self, parent)

            self.min = min
            self.max = max

        def validate(self, s, pos):
            print 'validate(): ', type(s), type(pos), s, pos

            if self.max > -1 and len(s) > self.max:
                return (QtGui.QValidator.Invalid, pos)

            if self.min > -1 and len(s) < self.min:
                return (QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate, pos)

            return (QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable, pos)

        def fixup(self, s):
            pass


    class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

            self.editLine = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.validator = ValidStringLength(0,5,self)

            self.editLine.setValidator(self.validator)

            layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
            layout.addWidget(self.editLine)

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 100)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt docs:

*fixup() is provided for validators that can repair some user errors. The default implementation does nothing. QLineEdit, for example, will call fixup() if the user presses Enter (or Return) and the content is not currently valid. This allows the fixup() function the opportunity of performing some magic to make an Invalid string Acceptable.*

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html

So yes, if your 'string cleaning' is an attempt to correct the user's input, `fixup` should be the correct place to do this.

EDIT:

This should capitalize the first four characters:

```
def validate(self, s, pos):
    print 'validate(): ', type(s), type(pos), s, pos

    n = min(4,s.count())
    if s.left(n).compare(s.left(n).toUpper()):
        return (QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate, pos)
    else:
        return (QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable, pos)

def fixup(self, s):
    n = min(4, s.count())
    s.replace(0, n, s.left(n).toUpper())
```

Comment: From where fixup() method should be called? And how to return an updated (cleaned) string and to update a lineEdit with it? Please post some example.. let's say we want to capitalize first four characters...

Comment: You don't have to call it yourself if your using a lineEdit. If the validator status is not `Acceptable` the lineEdit will call `fixup` and you can modify the string inplace (QStrings are mutable, in contrast to python strings). If the modified string is valid, the lineEdit will change the displayed text. I added a tested example.

Comment: FWIW: You might want to look into using the api 2 for QStrings, which will automatically convert all QStrings to python strings. Hence you wouldn't have to use the quite un-pythonic C++ string manipulation functions. In this case, `fixup` and `validate` will have to return the modified string.

Comment: Great job Sebastian! Thanks for the info!